# Issue for calling 2 function with with one click and 1st should save before 2nd

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

How we can add 2 function with one `ng-click`. I try like this : 
  `ng-click="Save(); Send();"`

but I want to save first then send. Both function having API calls.

Comment: can't you just call send() from the save() method?

Comment: No. Because i have one button for save and second button to save and send. So i can't call send function from save.

Comment: or create a SaveAndSend() function and call that instead?

Comment: I have two different API. As requirement i can't create new api and one function with one api.

Comment: it probably makes sense that you provide the (or at least the main parts) save() and send() function.

Answer (score 0):

call a function like this ng-click="callto2functions()"

```
$scope.callto2functions =function(){$scope.save();$scope.send();}
```

Comment: still does not work when both functions handles a promise

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that both your functions return a promise when they are doing api calls (at least they should do that)

but when you chain them they will be fire immediately. since they are promises you can chain them with .then(). this is not possible in the template, so you can build a separate function that handles that case

```
function saveAndSend() {
    save()
       .then(function(savedData) {
            return send();
        });
```

Comment: savedData ?? I am getting error.

Comment: because you probably do not return a promise from your save method. maybe you should check a tutorial for that. otherwise you cannot chain promise-functions

Comment: Also getting error at =>

Comment: $scope.saveAndsend = function saveAndSend() {
        $scope.Save()
           .then(savedData => {
               return $scope.Send();
           });

Comment: I am getting syntax error for   =>

Comment: yeah i updated my answer. it is not possible to declare functions inside ng-click, so i guess you have to go with either a 3rd function or call the send from the save

Comment: but I am getting error for syntax error for =>

Comment: @DeveshKhosla updated my answer with the old syntax, this is ES6 syntax :)